# Cryptic Mastermind

Tags: word, cryptic-clues, mastermind

And now for something completely different: Cryptic Mastermind!

Given below are five sets of five cryptic clues each, all resulting in five-letter words. The black and white pegs, like in regular Mastermind, indicate the number of correct letters. A black peg indicates a correct letter that is in the correct position; a white peg indicates a correct letter that is in the wrong position. The challenge is to correctly deduce the hidden word based on the five guesses and the corresponding black and white pegs.

After finding the five hidden words, the black and white pegs next to those again hint towards a final hidden word.

Good luck!

***N.B.:*** The six (5 + 1) hidden words are all existing English words and they can be found in a standard English dictionary. This information is important and should be used when figuring out the hidden words. I haven't tested this puzzle yet, so I hope it's doable. If it proves to be too difficult I will provide hints as needed.

[image: Cryptic Mastermind]

Comment: What a great system for intertwining word clues!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The final word is:

> **MAGIC**.

I had missed three of the clues, but Silenius has helped me to fill in the blanks.

**#1**

> ```
> MOODS O     States of mind of a weird sinful city: SODOM*
> CHARM XO    Hurt with a hundred to enchant: C (100) + HARM
> FORKS       Branches tableware: dd
> GROWL O     Rumble of a Greek nocturnal bird: GR + OWL
> ALPHA XXO   First, a mountain combined with the sound of laughter: ALP + HA
>
> LLAMA
> ```

**#2**

> ```
> BEATS O     Defeats a crazy monster: BEAST*
> LOGIC XO    Reasoning hidden in catalog icons: in cataLOG ICons
> SANDS O     Polishes Sam & Sue initially: S + AND + S
> LOWER       Beheaded blossom is inferior: f[LOWER]
> THINK OOOO  Consider a slender eleventh: THIN + K (11th)
>
> NIGHT
> ```

**#3**

> ```
> REMIT XOOO  Give back a returned hourglass: TIMER<
> THROW XX    Toss that ends up in the fourth row: in fourTH ROW
> MOTHS XOO   Heartless kissers fly by night: MO[u]THS
> FEMUR XOO   A flightless bird in France produces a bone: EMU in FR
> ENTER OOO   Come in and use a keyboard: dd
>
> TERMS
> ```

**#4**

> ```
> CHECK XXO   Bill is a potential mate: dd
> YEARN O     Why make money? It's what you long for: Y + EARN
> WATCH XX    Observe this Swiss product: dd
> ELBOW       Arm part modified downstairs: BELOW*
> NIECE XXO   Family member who is kind, embracing the irrational: E in NICE
>
> CINCH
> ```

**#5**

> ```
> ASSES O     Endlessly evaluate some donkeys: [ASSES]s
> REALM XOO   A genuine thousand in this region: REAL + M
> SPICY X     Hot, like Victoria or Geri: cd referring to Spice Girls
> LATEX O     Rubber basis for a former partner of long: LAT (lat/long) + EX
> MILES XO    Disturbed filth makes many yards: SLIME*
>
> MERRY
> ```

**Final**

> ```
> LLAMA OO
> NIGHT XO
> TERMS O
> CINCH OO
> MERRY X
>
> MAGIC
> ```

Comment: That was .. awesome and quick! :) +1

Comment: Bill is a potential mate = CHECK (ddef)

Comment: "Rubber basis for a former partner of long" might be LATEX (although the wordplay is unclear... a play on LATE EX maybe...)

Comment: Oh, yes, some people call their bills checks. That makes the partial answer for #4 CINCH, which fortunately doesn't break the overall answer.

Comment: Ah, good. Lat and Long are partners in geo coordinates.

Comment: Heartless kissers fly by night = MO(u)THS

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's complete now. I also needed to amend two partial answers (album > llama; finch, pinch > cinch) in the process, but I think it checks out now.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some of the cryptics:

## 1

States of mind of a weird sinful city

> MOODS (SODOM*) Techidiot

Branches tableware

> FORKS  (ddef)

Rumble of a Greek nocturnal bird

> GROWL (GR + OWL)

First, a mountain combined with the sound of laughter

> ALPHA (ALP+HA)

## 2

Reasoning hidden in catalog icons

> LOGIC (_LOG IC_)

Polishes Sam & Sue initially

> SANDS (S+AND+S)

## 3

Heartless kissers fly by night

> MOUTHS (MO(u)THS)

A flightless bird in France produces a bird

> FEMUR (F(EMU)R)

## 4

Bill is a potential mate

> CHECK (ddef)

Observe this Swiss product

> WATCH (ddef)

## 5

Endlessly evaluate some donkeys

> ASSES (ASSES(s))

Rubber basis for a former partner of long

> LATEX (LAT+EX, a play on abbreviations for *latitude* and *longitude*, as pointed out by M Oehm)

Comment: 1/1  - **MOODS** (anag sodom-sinful city)

Comment: Thanks! Just got that one myself when I realized indirect anagrams are being used here.

Comment: 3/2 - **THROW** hidden at the end. Yeah. I am working on that. Trying to find the first word

Comment: @Techidiot, M Oehm just posted a fairly complete solution.

Comment: Hah! Great. :) Didn't see that.

Comment: What does the text in the brackets for Branches tableware represent?

Comment: @Rob, it's a fairly standard annotation for [*double definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword#Double_definition).

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

**1**

Hurt with a hundred to enchant

> C+HARM

Branches tableware

> FORKS ddef

Reasoning hidden in catalog icons

> LOGIC hidden in clue

**2**

Defeats a crazy monster

> BEATS* (beast, indirect anagram!!! D: )

Beheaded blossom is inferior

> [F]  LOWER

**3**

Give back a returned hourglass

> REMIT?? I'm not to sure about this one, it's an obscure word.

Family member who is kind, embracing the irrational

> NI(E)CE

Come in and use a keyboard

> ENTER (dodgy ddef)

**4**

Arm part modified is downstairs

> BELOW* (elbow, indirect anagram!!! D: )

**5**

Endlessly evaluate some donkeys

> ASSES  [S]

Hot, like Victoria or Geri

> SPICE or SPICY

Disturbed filth makes many miles

> MILES* (slime, indirect anagram!!! D: )